# How to Block the user from opening same information in two different tabs/window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my application I need to block the user from from opening a same link in two different  tabs / windows (link is dynamic one not static ), Since the link generated id basis i wont allow user to open a same id information in different tabs.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: may I ask why you are doing this?

Comment: Technically, you can't, at least not effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you use window.open() giving a name to the window, it will not open more than one window/tab.

Example:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "myWindow");
```

If you have an id to make the difference between windows, the code could be like this:

```
window.open("url_for_id", "window" + id);
```

Comment: It does not apply if you open the window from a button, for instance (see http://jsfiddle.net/kk2cu/).  Of course users can copy/paste the URL in multiple tabs/windows, but the average user probably won't

Comment: I need it for new tab and new parant window no for child window. do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that. 
But you can do like this
Generate a token everytime user view a page and store it to session as well as in the page
You can prevent user submit data from both tab

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest you could come would be to:

- Only provide the information to logged in users
- Generate a random token for each page (and track which tokens are associated with which pages)
- Use Ajax to ping the server every *n* seconds, passing the token in the request
- If the server responds with "Have received different token for same page from same user within *n times 3* seconds" or no response is received, then `document.body.innerHTML = ''`

This is, of course, a horrible thing to do to users and can be easily defeated by hacking the JS in a debug tool or by just copy/pasting or taking a screen shot of the information.

**Web browsers are not designed to restrict what their users can down with the information they fetch**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of local storage to flag page opened in load activity and reset flag in unload in load check if flag is set then restrict else allow.